# How to handle the error 403 'Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user'?

Tags: python, bots, telebot

How to handle the error 403 'Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user'? I have a Telegram bot for anonymous chat using a MySQL database, and it occasionally throws this error even when no one is using the bot. I've tried error handling to prevent the code from terminating on error and continuing to run, but the code behaves incorrectly after the error. How can I handle this error so that it doesn't impact the bot's operation?

I tried such an error handler.

```
while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0, timeout=20)
    except telebot.apihelper.ApiException as e:
        if e.result.status_code == 400:
            print(f"Error 400: Bad Request - {e.result.reason}")
        elif e.result.status_code == 401:
            print(f"Error 401: Unauthorized - {e.result.reason}")
        elif e.result.status_code == 403:
            print(f"Error 403: Forbidden - {e.result.reason}")
        elif e.result.status_code == 404:
            print(f"Error 404: Not Found - {e.result.reason}")
        elif e.result.status_code == 429:
            print(f"Error 429: Too Many Requests - {e.result.reason}")
        elif e.result.status_code == 500:
            print(f"Error 500: Internal Server Error - {e.result.reason}")
        else:
            print(f"Unknown HTTP Error {e.result.status_code}: {e.result.reason}")
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == mysql.connector.errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            print(f"Error: Access denied for MySQL - {err}")
        elif err.errno == mysql.connector.errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            print(f"Error: Database does not exist - {err}")
        else:
            print(f"MySQL error: {err}")
    except KeyError as e:
        print(f"KeyError: {e}")
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f"ValueError: {e}")
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(f"FileNotFoundError: {e}")
    except IOError as e:
        print(f"IOError: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unknown error: {e}")
```

Comment: What's the incorrect behavior and what do you want to happen?

Comment: My bot functions as a chat that connects users based on several criteria they choose. When I launch the bot, it operates normally for a while, but then I encounter a 403 error 'Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user.' With my custom error handler that I've written here, the bot doesn't terminate, but it operates incorrectly (as I've noticed, when entering search parameters for a chat partner, the bot claims to have found a partner even when it's not the case, and then it stops responding to commands).

Answer (score 0):

> it occasionally throws this error even when no one is using the bot.

The error is unlikely to occur "when no one is using the bot". It might be raised when e.g. bot is trying to send (or interacting in some other way) a message to a user.

You could add an exception handler. Such errors will be sent to that handler and you could process them. Examples might be found [here](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/discussions/1939)